Start Date to End Date owing the part
I have the following data in my table.



id
part_num
modify_date
order_number
vendor_num




637
pn23053
3/18/24 15:03
on-542
13


637
pn23053
2/8/24 5:10
on-542
13


637
pn23053
2/8/24 5:00
on-542
13


637
pn23053
2/8/24 5:00
on-542
1


637
pn23053
1/8/24 21:56
on-542
1


637
pn23053
1/8/24 21:56
on-542
13


637
pn23053
11/4/23 18:4
on-542
13


637
pn23053
11/4/23 18:4
on-542
13


637
pn23053
11/4/23 18:4
on-542
20


895
pn95345
6/8/24 17:20
on-691
14


895
pn95345
3/17/24 16:30
on-691
14


895
pn95345
3/8/24 13:50
on-691
14


895
pn95345
3/8/24 13:50
on-691
5


895
pn95345
2/6/24 21:57
on-691
5


895
pn95345
2/6/24 21:57
on-691
21


895
pn95345
2/3/24 18:57
on-691
21


895
pn95345
1/8/24 18:57
on-691
21



I have tried using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY modify_date, owner_id ORDER BY modify_date ASC) AS row_num, but the data turned out to be funky. There are two unique part numbers in the table, but many vendors are associated with each part. So, I need to know when the vendor starts and ends owning the part. I expect the result to be...



id
part_num
modify_date
order_number
vendor_num
End-modify_date




637
pn23053
2/8/24 5:00
on-542
13
current Date


637
pn23053
1/8/24 21:56
on-542
1
2/8/24 5:00


637
pn23053
11/4/23 18:4
on-542
13
1/8/24 21:56


637
pn23053
11/4/23 18:4
on-542
20
11/4/23 18:4


895
pn95345
3/8/24 13:50
on-691
14
current Date


895
pn95345
2/6/24 21:57
on-691
5
3/8/24 13:50


895
pn95345
1/8/24 18:57
on-691
21
2/6/24 21:57




Azure Data Studio is just an IDE; what RDBMS are you using?

From the result, I clearly see partition by PN.  Why is the PN not in the PARTITION BY?

You should use lead, and case when. Could you please try this? It gave me this output.

SELECT
    id,
    part_num,
    order_number,
    vendor_num,
    MIN(modify_date) AS modify_date,
    COALESCE(MAX(modify_date), NOW()) AS end_modify_date
FROM sys.visits
GROUP BY
    id,
    part_num,
    order_number,
    vendor_num
ORDER BY
    id,
    part_num,
    order_number,
    vendor_num,
    modify_date;


I got the following error Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 160 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

what is your date format? some date looked like this in you data '11/4/23 18:4 ' Maybe that is why.. Could you convert it? ```sql CONVERT(DATETIME, modify_date, 101) AS modify_date,

my modify_date colulmn 2023-12-02 21:43:03.013

I got the code to run without an error by replacing 'current Date' with GETDATE(). However, the result is still not what I'm expecting; multiple rows still appear. For example, for vendor 21, I should see only one row with modify_date equal to 1/8/24 18:57 and End-modify_date equal to 2/6/24 21:57

@newbie21 I edited the code.

it works.  Thank you
